# Embed view controller in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

Initially i just presented the view like this and it worked fine.

```
let editSpotVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditSpotViewController") as! EditSpotViewController

self.presentViewController(editSpotVc, animated: false) { () -> Void in
    editSpotVc.addImage(ImageTransformationUtil.scaleImageTo(newWidth: 1080, image: image))
    editSpotVc.updateMapAndReverseGeocode(photoCoordiantes)
}
```

I need to have the view controller embedded in a navigation controller now. My solution (below) doesn't work. The program crashes because it’s finding nil when it runs the editSpotVC methods.

```
let editSpotVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditSpotViewController") as! EditSpotViewController
let editSpotNavVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditSpotNavController")

self.presentViewController(editSpotNavVc, animated: false) { () -> Void in
    editSpotVc.addImage(ImageTransformationUtil.scaleImageTo(newWidth: 1080, image: image))
    editSpotVc.updateMapAndReverseGeocode(photoCoordiantes)
}
```

How can I make this work smoothly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Go to Storyboard -> **Select the viewController you want to embed** -> **Editor** -> **Embed in** -> **Navigation Controller**

2.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourViewController)
```

In this case,

```
let editSpotVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditSpotViewController") as! EditSpotViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editSpotVc)
```

Comment: This was the simple solution I was hoping for. Thanks!